# How to check a Windows.Data.Json.JsonObject for certain value?

Tags: c#, json

I have a

```
Windows.Data.Json.JsonObject jsonObject
```

with the content

```
{
    "status": 0
}
```

I can check if the value "status" exists with the following code:

```
IJsonValue j;
bool statusValueExists = jsonObject.TryGetValue("status", out j);
```

Is there another way to check for the existance of value "status" that does not need an IJsonValue-object (here: j) and does not need a try-catch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`ContainsKey`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows.data.json.jsonobject.containskey.aspx) method:

```
if (jsonObject.ContainsKey("name"))
{ }
```